# SL Skeleton, Avatar Workbench, MH Avatar import problem

Tags: import, blend-files

When I import my MH mhx2 into Avatar Workbench for SL, the worbench.blend file is in right ortho, so it faces right. When I import my MHX2 avatar from MH, it faces to the front, so I can't rig it to the SL fitted mesh skeleton. In SL, there is a way to rotate the Av from side to front, but I can't seem to find that same axis control in Blender.

Because of the scale issue in MH, it only imports with the proper scale if I go from MH to Sculptris to Blender, and I have to use the avatarworkbench.blend file, but when I do that I get the problem I wrote about above.

If I just import the MHX2 file directly, it only shows up in 3D Full view, it is turned towards the left slightly, and I also can't scale or rotate it.

I just want to attach the fitted mesh SL Skeleton (with the additional collision bones for fitted mesh) to my MH avatar without so much fuss, and I need to find out how to "rotate" my MH Avatar to face front in avatar workbench.blend

P.S. Please don't answer this question by saying "get Avastar" or something to that effect, because I can't afford it right now.

Answer (score 1):

Very easy:) Select your model (all of it...rig and all) in object mode. Now press <kbd>R</kbd> and <kbd>Z</kbd> you can now rotate with mouse...get it as close as possible then fine tune to exactly 90 deg or -90 deg in the left panel very bottom. After you're done, don't forget to press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>A</kbd> and save rotation scale etc.

Comment: You can press `R`>`Z` and then type `90` or `-90` as well, this will give the exact rotational value